# Create widget like igoogle in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have to create webapplication like igoogle.So how can i create widgets?

Please tell me from start.

Thanks

Pankaj Pareek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not opensource but try looking at RadDock

[Dock Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx)

hth

**update**

[Ext Portal](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2/examples/portal/portal.html)

this is open... I think! [Licence](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/license/)

Comment: Could anyone tell me how i will do that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DropThings](http://code.google.com/p/dropthings/).  It's well documented and should be a great place to start.